# Ensure/lock a program to run on Raspberry Pi only?

Tags: python, hardware, c++

Are there any characteristics/ lock available so that the program would fail to run on any other device except Raspberry Pi. I have thought about using GPIO with external circuits but would prefer just using software based solution for this problem.

Edit: To people who make assumptions before reading the question. The goal is not for Users to prevent copying. The goal is to engage people in using Raspberry Pi and work on hardware rather than running emulators or using other Linux machines to test their skills at program efficiency. Same machine cycle, same cpu/gpu.

Comment: What's your goal with this? Are you trying to stop the program running on other devices to prevent copying, for example, or some other reason?

Comment: @Aurora0001 No my goal is program runs on Raspberry Pi only so users dont have hardware advantage over other users. A level playing field for all participants

Comment: Whatever you do, someone will circumvent it.

Comment: @GlenYates No I am sure there is a variable that is unique to Pi only. If you have ever programmed in ASM only you would know what I am looking for.

Comment: @GlenYates Try circumventing using Cuda on Amd

Answer (score 1):

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library will only work on the Raspberry Pi as it uses features unique to the Pi SoC.  None of the Pi "clones" use the same SoC.

Comment: How should the OP expect it to fail (and trap and utilise that exception) if it's run on a clone, please?  He may not have access to a clone to test it.